# How to show value when user editing in form using angular

Tags: angular

I want to edit and show value in form when user editing please help me how to show value in angular.

**edit-blog.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Blog } from '../_models/blog';
import { UserService } from '../_services';
import { User } from '../_models'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationServiceService } from '../_services';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-blog',
  templateUrl: './edit-blog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-blog.component.css']
})
export class EditBlogComponent implements OnInit {
  editBlogForm: FormGroup;
  users: User[] = [];
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,

    private authenticationService: AuthenticationServiceService,
    private userService: UserService) { }
    get f() { return this.editBlogForm.controls; }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.editBlogForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: [this.users, Validators.required],
      blog: [this.users, Validators.required],
    });
  }
  //get f() { return this.editBlogForm.controls; }
  editUserBlog(id:number) {
    this.userService.editUserBlog(id).pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {
      users = users;
      console.log(users);
    });

  }
  onSubmit(user: User) {
    this.userService.update(user).subscribe(user => {
      user = user;

    });
  }


}
```

And below is my edit-blog.componet.html i want to show value in this form plase help how to show value.

**edit-blog.component.html**

```
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 60px">
                <h2>Update your blog here..</h2>
                <form [formGroup]="editBlogForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="users.title" formControlName="title" class="input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.title.errors }"
                            placeholder="Title" />
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.title.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.title.errors.required">Title is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <app-ngx-editor type="text" formControlName="blog" height="250px" minHeight="50px" class=""
                            [placeholder]="'Enter text here...'" [spellcheck]="true" [ngClass]="htmlContent"></app-ngx-editor>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.blog.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.blog.errors.required">Blog is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>

                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i do not get value when editing the form please help me how to show the value .thnk you in advance.

Comment: In Angular you choose if you want to use Reactive Form OR Template Driven Form. If you use Reactive Form, NOT use [(ngModel)], see the doc https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. Tip: if use ReactiveForm, you can write in your .html {{editFormGroup?.value|json}} to check the values

Comment: Your `users` variable is an array. And you are trying to use it as an object.

Comment: please code for me ...@Arcteezy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a link to the angular docs concerning forms: [Forms Overview in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview)

In Angular, there are two major methods of creating forms - Reactive approach and Template-driven approach. First thing is you have to decide which method you want to employ first.

The reactive method is a programmatic approach, your form is created in your .ts file and synchronised with the HTML form template with the application of directives such as formGroup (in the opening form tag) and formControlName attached to values you set for this in your .ts file and in their respective input tags.

The Template-driven approach is done mainly in your template i.e .html file.... In this case, the directive [ngModel] is used as the formControl and the html "name" attribute is present to help you track the form value in the form object on your console.

To show a preset value in your form however, kindly make up your mind about the approach you want to employ first.
For TD Approach - Simply use the HTML attribute "value" and set it to your required value. e.g for username input; value="Benneee"....
For Reactive approach - after declaring the FormGroup object's type, in the place of assigning the form object to its defined value and assigning the different formcontrol names, you can do something like this:
 "username": new FormControl("Benneee");

I hope this does help or at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing, Dinesh:

On second thought, kindly read carefully through my first message and understand carefully, then I think you should just remove that ngModel directive in that HTML template to begin with.

Then in your .ts file, within your ngOnInit file, simply do this:

```
console.log('my form: ', this.editBlogForm)
```

That should solve this issue.